# Custom metadata in RTF picture?

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

I need to be able to identify pictures in a valid RTF string.

**Picture example:**

```
{\pict\wmetafile8\picw503\pich476\picwgoal285\pichgoal270
010009000003fe0200000000d502000000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000
000c0212001300030000001e0004000000070104000400000007010400d5020000410b2000cc00
120013000000000012001300000000002800000013000000120000000100080000000000000000
... more hex here ...
002701ffff030000000000
}
```

I am using `RTF 1.6` and the editor I display the content in needs valid rtf code.

I need to be able to identify the images and replace them placeholders when transferring the content between the server and the client. For this I am thinking of using regular expressions to replace the images with string placeholders.

Is there a way to identify the image using custom metadata fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the [RTF 1.6 documentation](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading44) I found that this is possible.

The 1.6 spec allows you to identify an image inside an RTF document using two attributes: `\bliptagN` and `\blipuid XXXXX`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work in my particular case. I am using an instance of the `RichTextBox` class to show the content to the user.

It turns out the `RichTextBox` control doesn't support the full RTF 1.6 specification and automatically cleans all non-supported metadata when inserting a picture.